# Two Error in Drop Down Menu

Tags: css, drop-down-menu

Please help me, i get two type of error in "Drop Down Menu"

## First error:

when I move my cursor to the right direction in the sub-menu (Example: Portfolio 2), I get a black box. This does not happen if my cursor is above the text (Example: Portfolio 2).
 - Print Screen: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JYS8L.jpg

## Second error:

This is my second error, view this print screen: https://i.stack.imgur.com/N7Wp1.jpg

View Demo live Link oh here: http://jsbin.com/akugin/1/edit

This is my html content:

```
<div id="navigasi_menu">
<div class="navigasi_list">
    <div class="menu-main-menu-container">
    <ul class="menu" id="menu-main-menu">

        <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-6" id="menu-item-6">
        <a href="/">Home</a></li>

        <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-7" id="menu-item-7"><a href="#">Portfolio</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-8" id="menu-item-8"><a href="#">Portfolio 1</a></li>
                <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-9" id="menu-item-9"><a href="#">Portfolio 2</a></li>
                <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-10" id="menu-item-10"><a href="#">Portfolio 3</a></li>
                <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-11" id="menu-item-11"><a href="#">Portfolio 4</a></li>
                <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-12" id="menu-item-12"><a href="#">Portfolio 5</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>

        <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-349" id="menu-item-349"><a href="#">Category</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-245" id="menu-item-245"><a href="/?cat=3">Lifestyle</a></li>
                <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-246" id="menu-item-246"><a href="/?cat=4">Interior</a></li>
                <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-367" id="menu-item-367"><a href="/?cat=10">Examples</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>

        <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-348" id="menu-item-348"><a href="#">Features</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-343" id="menu-item-343"><a href="/?page_id=286">Shortcode</a></li>
                <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-366" id="menu-item-366"><a href="/?p=351">Sample Images</a></li>
                <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-378" id="menu-item-378"><a href="/?page_id=2">Sample Page</a></li>
                <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-397" id="menu-item-397"><a href="/?p=146">Sample Comments</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>

        <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-14" id="menu-item-14"><a href="http://www.forum.com/">Support</a></li>

    </ul>
    </div>  
</div>
</div>
```

This is my css content:

```
#navigasi_menu {
background:#ffffff;
height:45px;
width:1188px;
float:left;
display:block;
box-shadow:0px 1px 4px #000000;
border-bottom:1px solid #D4D4D4;
border-top:1px solid #D4D4D4;
z-index:9999;
}

.navigasi_list {
height:45px;
margin-left:0;
text-align:left;
}

.navigasi_list a {
color:#333333;
font-family:'bebasneueregular','Oswald','Helvetica Neue','Helvetica',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
padding:0px 17px 0px 19px;
text-decoration:none;
}

#navigasi_menu ul {
list-style:none;
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
}

#navigasi_menu li {
border-right:2px solid #ffffff;
position:relative;
float:left;
font-size:25px;
height:45px;
}

#navigasi_menu li a {
line-height:2;
height:45px;
display:inline-block;
}

#navigasi_menu li:hover {
background:#999999;
float:left;
list-style:none;
}

#navigasi_menu ul li ul {
display:none;
float:left;
left:0;
position:absolute;
z-index:99999;
}

#navigasi_menu ul li ul li {
position:relative;
float:left;
font-size:23px;
width:180px;
color:#ffffff;
border-right:0px;
}

#navigasi_menu ul li ul li:hover {
background:#333333;
color:#B2B2B2;
}

#navigasi_menu ul li ul li a:hover {
background:#333333;
color:#B2B2B2;
}

#navigasi_menu ul li:hover > ul {
display:block;
background:#999999;
border-top:5px solid #cccccc;
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix both issues, add `overflow:hidden` to your `#navigasi_menu ul li ul` rule.

```
#navigasi_menu ul li ul {
    display:none;
    float:left;
    left:0;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:99999;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

And create a new rule:

```
#navigasi_menu ul li ul li a {
    /**/
    display:block;
    width:100%;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/44hFm/)**

Comment: And in your opinion, is it a good solution if the half of the last letter in 'Features' last element is cut off?

Answer (score 0):

Use this...

In the class `#navigasi_menu ul li ul li`

Change this `width:180px;` for `width:250px;`

see this **[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/ibekug/1)**

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have fixed the first issue (by changing the text color on hover).

As for the second issue, it's best not to set heights on elements, as you get this overflow problem if the content can't fit within that height. It's better to set line-height in cases like this, so I'd advise you to change the `height` on the  element to `line-height` and simply remove the `height` on the `<li>`s:

```
#navigasi_menu li {
border-right:2px solid #ffffff;
position:relative;
float:left;
font-size:25px;
height:45px;  /* remove this */
}

#navigasi_menu li a {
line-height:2; /* remove this */
line-height:45px; /* add this */
display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Actually the first issue is there. The element for hover is smaller than the container so if you hover over the right side the black box shows up.

Answer (score 0):

That's a little bit messy. But for the problems:

1st problem: Because you have separate style for the `li:hover` and the `li a:hover`. You can change to this:

```
#navigasi_menu ul li ul li:hover {
background:#333333;
color:#B2B2B2;
}

#navigasi_menu ul li ul li:hover a { /* Change was here from ...ul li a:hover */
background:#333333;
color:#B2B2B2;
}
```

2nd problem: you set a width to the list element, which is too small. Make it wider:

```
#navigasi_menu ul li ul li {
position:relative;
float:left;
font-size:23px;
min-width:180px;
  width: 210px; /* Change was here from 180px */
color:#ffffff;
border-right:0px;
}
```

That was a quick fix, but if I were you, I would check the CSS of a good, working example.

The modified JSBIN: http://jsbin.com/eyoziy/1/edit